# How Do I Remove references to an old Heroku app in local git folder?

Tags: git, heroku

I deleted a heroku app reinitialized the local repository but when I try to add the new remote repository it won't let me add the new remote because the remote already exists but with the old name. I tried doing a rename but that didn't work either because of course the old app no  longer exists. When I run "git remote -v" I get:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:fierce-reef-7370.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:fierce-reef-7370.git (push)
```

both are referencing the old app. I have no idea how to remove these so that I can push to the new remote heroku app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `git remote set-url` to change the url:

```
git remote set-url heroku <new-url>
```

Alternatively, you can use `git remote rm` to remove a remote by name:

```
git remote rm heroku
```